# NSDateFormatter NSString w/ day suffix to NSDdate

Tags: objective-c, nsdateformatter

I'm trying to use only a NSDateFormatter to format string representation of a date/time to an NSDate object. The issue is that I can't figure out how to allow the ordinal suffixes in the format.

So lets say I have a string 
**"Wednesday, August 11th 2010 8:00 PM"**

What one line NSDate dateFormat should I use?

Like "**EEEE, MMM dd'th' yyyy h:mm a"** would work, but that will only work for ordinal days ending in 'th', whereas i need a single format that will allow for 1st, 2nd, 3rd, 4th 5th etc.

It seems like a wildcard character in the format string to accomplish this. I've tried a few things like: % * ?

Comment: See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1283045/ordinal-month-day-suffix-option-for-nsdateformatter-setdateformat

Comment: That's for the other way around. NSDate to NSString, i need NSString to NSDate

Comment: Generally, NSDateFormatter gets confused if you try to parse a date containing a day of the week.  Best to strip that off and just parse the remainder.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is apparently not possible with the NSDateFormatter.

Comment: I'm giving up and manually replacing references of `"st, " "nd, " "rd, " "th, "` with a space character `" "` before sending it through a dateformatter.  Makes things a bit more difficult, but it really is the only way since there is no wildcard character.....

Answer (score -1):

You want to use an NSDateFormatter like so:

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];    
[dateFormatter setDateStyle: NSDateFormatterLongStyle];
NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateString];
[dateFormatter release];
```

Either NSDateFormatterLongStyle or NSDateFormatterFullStyle should get you the results you're looking for.

Comment: I'm looking to pass in a custom string formatter, and not use the ones provided by the SDK.

Comment: according the docs, setting the date style doesn't help -- can't see any styles that support "1st", "2nd" etc. e.g. the long style just gives "November 23, 1937”. He wants "23rd".